# How to fix error with my first Hibernate project?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have been tried to make my first Hibernate project. I added following libraries into my project:

antlr-2.7.7
commons-collections-3.2.1
dom4j-1.6.1
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.1.Final
hibernate-core-4.1.0.Final
hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final
javassist-3.15.0-GA
jboss-logging-3.1.0.CR2
jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec-1.0.0.Final
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</property>

    <mapping class="com.nda.hibernate.Person"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Person.class:

```
package com.nda.hibernate;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Person {

    private String name;

    @Id
    private int number;

    public Person() {}

    public Person(String name, int number) {

        this.name=name;
        this.number=number;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number=number;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
```

I have Denwer installed. Parameters for using: login - root, password is empty. Server is localhost, and has database "test" with table "person"(CHAR(50) name, INT(10) number - primary key)

Main.class:

```
    SessionFactory sessions=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=sessions.openSession();
```

It doesn't work. I have got some errors:

```
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.1.Final}
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.1.0.Final}
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.DTDEntityResolver resolveEntity
WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
INFO: HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost/test]
03.03.2012 14:11:07 org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
03.03.2012 14:11:08 org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
03.03.2012 14:11:08 org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
03.03.2012 14:11:08 org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any exception in that log. Could you please show a log with an exception.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

None of those look like errors to me - they're just log lines. The only "problem" is a warning here:

> WARN: HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!

That's only a warning - worth fixing, but it sounds like it's not *terribly* urgent.

Everything else is just at INFO level... so don't worry about them. Just keep going, and see whether your code does what you expect in terms of database access.

Answer (score 27):

I was also having the same problem.
After some Googling, I solved the problem.

All you have to do is to change the namespace "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" to "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd"
as specified in the [Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-15659).

Answer (score 7):

It's easy
In your file xml hibernate configuration you must change the line

```
http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd
```

to

```
http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd
```

Answer (score 0):

**Person.class** should implements *serializable*, but it seems that the main problem  you have is the Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!

See you.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated by Neo182 and Jon Skeet, these are not really errors you are dealing with. Just 1 of these messages is even a warning.

To avoid that warning, you simply need to complete your Hibernate upgrade by following the [Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-15659). That is, in your hibernate.cfg.xml, just change the namespace "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd" to "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd".