# Warning shown when creating hibernate.cfg.xml in Eclipse

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, hibernate

Here is my code in file named hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/HeartJar</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping resource="com/heartjar/bean/User.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

There was a waining saying `Stream not available`at line 2
Although warnings don't have bad influences to my project.But Understanding how to solve the problem is useful for me,a beginner in JavaWeb.Thank you for your answer

Comment: Could you have look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867174/error-shown-when-creating-hibernate-project-in-eclipse

Comment: I have read it.But it's not helpful for me.

Comment: It's strange.Sometimes the waining appears,sometimes it disappears.

Comment: Don't worry, sometimes it happens but doesn't matter, network could fails but leave it, the most important is your project is being built