# how to fix recognized obsolete hibernate namespace waring massage

Tags: hibernate

```
Configuration [INFO] HHH000043: Configuring from resource: com/logiware/webtool/hibernates/hibernate.cfg.xml

Configuration [INFO] HHH000040: Configuration resource: com/logiware/webtool/hibernates/hibernate.cfg.xml

Configuration [INFO] HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/logiware/webtool/hibernate/domain/BookingTerminal.hbm.xml

DTDEntityResolver [WARN] HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!

Configuration [INFO] HHH000221: Reading mappings from resource: com/logiware/webtool/hibernate/domain/Bkgtemplate.hbm.xml
```

My Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<!-- Generated by MyEclipse Hibernate Tools.                    -->
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="dialect">com.gp.cong.hibernate.DirtyDialect</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">50</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
<property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>
<property name="connection.is-connection-validation-required">true</property>
```

Answer (score 10):

Just change your hibernate.cfg.xml file namespace definitions to as below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration.dtd">
```

Similarly for the hibernate mapping files, change it to as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC  
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"  
 "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping.dtd">
```

Answer (score 3):

That is a correct answer.

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12134202/5218261